# Mongodb + elasticsearch + scala lift

Tags: scala, mongodb, elasticsearch, lift, mongodb-query

I Integrating MongoDB with Elastic Search

I have indexed the collection "person" in the database "testmongo" from the terminal with the following command:

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/_river/mongodb/_meta' -d '{ 
    "type": "mongodb", 
    "mongodb": { 
        "db": "testmongo", 
        "collection": "person"
    }, 
    "index": {
        "name": "mongoindex", 
        "type": "person" 
    }
}'
```

and add some data to the mongodb through mongo terminal:

```
use testmongo
var p = {firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe"}
db.person.save(p)
```

Use this command to search the data:

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/mongoindex/_search?q=firstName:John'
```

Until here everything works perfectly

My problem is this:

How to, I have to create the client node to query
I have the following code does not work:

```
    package code
    package snippet

    import net.liftweb._
    import http._
    import common._
    import util.Helpers._
    import scala.xml._
    import org.elasticsearch.node.NodeBuilder._
    import org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryBuilders._
    import collection.JavaConversions._


    class SearchTerms extends StatefulSnippet with Loggable{


      private var term = ""

      def dispatch = {
        case "render" => render _
      }

      def render( xhtml: NodeSeq ): NodeSeq = {

        def doSearchTerm {

          val node = nodeBuilder().client(true).node()
          val client = node.client()

          val query = queryString( term )
          val response = client
            .prepareSearch("A")
            .setTypes("B")
            .setQuery(query)
            .execute()
            .actionGet()

          val hits = response.getHits

          logger.info( "Found %d hits for query '%s'".format( hits.getTotalHits, term ) )

          hits.getHits.foreach(hit =>
            logger.info("* %s".format(hit.sourceAsMap()("text")))
          )

          client.close()
          node.close()
        }
```

What are the values ​​that I have to use in A and B to use the search function in scala lift

can someone please help me

thank you very much for your attention

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that it's:

- mongoindex as index name
- person as type name

So, something like:

```
      val response = client
        .prepareSearch("mongoindex")
        .setTypes("person")
        .setQuery(query)
        .execute()
        .actionGet()
```

Does it help?

BTW, term should contain something like "firstName:John"